# Ошибка при вставке BLOB через JayDeBeApi: ORA-01400: невозможно вставить NULL

Tags: python, sql, oracle, jdbc, blob

При попытке сделать вставку в таблицу с колонкой `BLOB`, вставляется пустое значение.

```
import jpype
import jpype.imports
import jaydebeapi

pic = open('out-1.png', 'rb')
z = pic.read()
con = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@URL',jars = "ojdbc6.jar")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO TAB (ID, PARAM, DATA) VALUES (:id, :param, :data)", 
    (3383782, "50002390872", z))
```

> jaydebeapi.DatabaseError: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: невозможно вставить NULL в ("TAB"."DATA")

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

---

PS: Долго пытался подобрать решение. Экспериментом выгрузил `BLOB` значение из другой таблицы и подставил вo вставку. Сработало. Пробовал через JPype создать объект `oracle.sql.BLOB` и туда записать. Но что-то совсем не пошло. Пришлось все-таки перейти на cx_Oracle, там такая конструкция работает. В итоге, решил на сервер положить программу и подключить RemoteAPP. Не совсем как хотел, надеялся распространять .exe и обновлять его, но все-таки первоначальная задача выполнена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недостаточно передать во вставку переменную типа байты, полученую при считывании из фйла. Она будет "понята" как `NULL`, в чём и причина ошибки.

Данные надо конвертировать согласно [Python Database API Specification v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#type-objects-and-constructors) в бинарный формат - `<java array 'byte[]'>`.

Ниже воспроизводимый пример, как это надо сделать.

Тестовая таблица:

```
create table tblob (filename varchar2 (64), data blob not null)
```

Код:

```
import jaydebeapi as jdb

fnam = '1234.png' 
file = open (fnam, 'rb')
pic = file.read ()

conn = jdb.connect (
    'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:me/me@db.srv.net/dbsvc', 
    jars='/path-to/ojdbc8.jar')
cur = conn.cursor ()
cur.execute ("insert into tblob values (:filename, :data)", (fnam, jdb.Binary (pic)))
cur.close ()
conn.close ()
```

Результат после выполнения:

```
select * from tblob
/
FILENAME DATA
-------- --------------------------------
1234.png 89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452
         00000048000000D408060000003F4965
         7F000000017352474200AECE1CE90000
         000467414D410000B18F0BFC61050000
         00097048597300000EC300000EC301C7
```